# Notation - the element with the maximum value in a different set

Tags: notation, index-notation

I have a question about the proper notation of the following (simplified) example:

I want to express that I choose the value $x_i \in S$, such that $f(x_i)$ is the maximum value in the set $\{ f(x_k) \}$ where $x_k \in S$.

I thought about the following notation: Choose $x_i \in S$ such that $f(x_i)=max_{x_k \in S}(f(x_k))$.

Is it correct?

Comment: You can use $x_i = \arg \max_{x_k\in S} f(x_k)$

Comment: @bames I'm not sure I understand why this notation is correct.

Comment: See the following wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arg_max.

Comment: @bames Sounds correct. Thanks.